# PHP - Email String In An Array of Domain Names

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of domain names such as:

```
stonybrook.edu
sunysuffolk.edu
harvard.edu
```

Then I have an input field where a user enters his or her .edu email address.

For example: someguy@mail.sunysuffolk.edu

Now I want to deny users registration who are not in the domain' array. So for example someone who tries to signup using someguy@princeton.edu will be denied because there is no 'princeton.edu' in the array.

I am trying to create a 'check' because I have to somehow match the email address to the array of domains.

I tried to use in_array but I am having trouble doing this. Here is what I have thus far:

```
<?php

    $domains = array('stonybrook.edu', 'sunysuffolk.edu', 'harvard.edu');

    $myEmail = 'sam@mail.sunysuffolk.edu';

    if (in_array($myEmail, $domains)) {

        echo 'You Are Allowed To Register!';

    }

?>
```

This fails. Now I thought about using strpos() but strpos() takes a string argument but my domains is an array. Right now my array is only 3 values but eventually that array will become very big so using a loop wouldn't be too efficient.

Can anyone provide me with any suggestions on how I could go about doing this validation? Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is how I managed to get it working:

```
<?php

$domains = array('stonybrook.edu', 'sunysuffolk.edu', 'harvard.edu');

$count = 0;

$myEmail = 'sam@mail.sunysuffolk.edu';

foreach ($domains as $domain) {

    if (strpos($myEmail, $domain) !== false) $count++;

}

if ($count > 0) echo 'You Are Allowed To Register!';

?>
```

Comment: Did you just watch The Social Network like I did??

Comment: Instead of proceed like this, just do an echo then a break in your if condition.

Comment: As per your `Edit/Fix`, you'll be faced with the same problem as `scrowler` mentioned `superspamuser@harvard.edu.yourmaliciousdomain.com` which will pass through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it:

```
$domains = array('stonybrook.edu', 'sunysuffolk.edu', 'harvard.edu');
$email  = 'sam@mail.sunysuffolk.edu';

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // Invalid email address
    // ....
    // Processing error
    // Returng user to re-enter email
}    

list($name,$domain) = explode('@',$email); // $domain=='mail.sunysuffolk.edu';
$domain = implode('.',array_slice(explode('.',$domain),-2,2)); // $domain=='sunysuffolk.edu';

if ( in_array(strtolower($domain),$domains)){
 print'You Are Allowed To Register!';
}
```

*EDIT ( for @danronmoon &  @Fred -ii-)*

I added email validation,but... Thinking, main goal  - show  working 
solution for start positions `$domains = array('stonybrook.edu', 'sunysuffolk.edu', 'harvard.edu');` and `$email  = 'sam@mail.sunysuffolk.edu';`. Filtration, validation  and others aspects go out beyond current OP question.

Comment: This works rather well, however as `danronmoon` stated in a comment, this would pass `sam\@mail.sunnyfolk.edu'` which I failed to test earlier --- So I suggested in using [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](http://php.net/manual/filter.filters.validate.php) in conjunction with it.

Comment: It was just a suggestion. All for the better good  ;-) which I did `+1` btw.

Comment: Exactly. You're the front-runner now ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This concatenates domain components incrementally and checks if they exist in the `$domains` array at each iteration

```
$domains = array('stonybrook.edu', 'sunysuffolk.edu', 'harvard.edu');
$email   = 'sam@whatever.sandwich.mail.sunysuffolk.edu';

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // not valid!
    exit('Not a valid email');
}

$email_domain = strtolower(explode('@', $email)[1]);

$email_domain_parts = explode('.', $email_domain);

$email_glue_arr = array();

$email_valid = false;

while ($email_domain_part = array_pop($email_domain_parts)) {
    array_unshift($email_glue_arr, $email_domain_part);
    $email_domain_str_to_test = implode('.', $email_glue_arr);


    if (in_array($email_domain_str_to_test, $domains)) {
         $email_valid = true;
         break;
    }
}  



if ($email_valid) {
    // OK
}
```

Comment: This one works fairly well, except that this will pass as OK `@mmail.sunysuffolk.edu` as will `@m.harvard.edu` --- So far, only `voodoo417's` answer works best.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `Now I want to deny users registration who are not in the domain' array` seems to be the whole crux of the question

Comment: @Fred-ii- By the same token, voodoo's code would allow 'sam\@mail.sunnyfolk.edu', which doesn't validate.  I added it for comprehensiveness, but some assumptions just have to be made if the OP doesn't explicitly ask for it.  We only have so much time to do these :)

Comment: You have a point there, good catch. I didn't test that possibility. Then it would be worthwhile to use [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](http://php.net/manual/filter.filters.validate.php) in conjunction with it.

Comment: And I agree on the `time` factor. I `+1` yours as well, because it does work fairly well, as I originally stated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$domains = array('stonybrook.edu', 'sunysuffolk.edu', 'harvard.edu');

$myEmail = array(
    'sam@mail.sunysuffolk.edu',
    'sam@mail.sunysuffolk.edue',
    'sam@ssunysuffolk.edu',
    'sam@mail.ssunysuffolk.edu',
    'sam@sunysuffolke.edu',
);

foreach ($myEmail AS $email) {
    $domainExp = explode('@', $email);
    $domainSplit = explode('.', $domainExp[1]);
    foreach ($domains AS $domain) {
        $count = count($domainSplit);
        if ($domainSplit[$count - 2] . '.' . $domainSplit[$count -1] == $domain) {
            echo $email . ' is allowed<br/>';
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `strtolower($domain[1])` for case compatibility

Comment: Yep but I didn't put all cleaning code needed like check if the @ exist and etc, etc...

Comment: You modified his example to make it work. He's anticipating the following email: 'sam@mail.sunysuffolk.edu'. You changed it to: 'sam@sunysuffolk.edu'

Comment: @scrowler But this wouldn't handle the sub domain. The email is sam@mail.sunysuffolk.edu.

Comment: @scrowler it was my initial code but this don't handle subdomains, that's why I updated the code.

Comment: Your edit worked for sub-domain `@mail.sunysuffolk.edu` but not for `@sunysuffolk.edu` --- thought you'd like to know.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I updated it again to add !== false for the strpos()

Comment: hey scrowler, example.email.address@with.lots.of.sub.domains.will.not.work.with.your.code.com. dumb ass

Comment: Now you got it perfect. @zeflex `+1`

Comment: Actually, found a slight bug. Entering `@ssunysuffolk.edu` with an extra `s` in front of `sunysuffolk.edu` let's it go by. As did `@sunysuffolk.eduu`

Comment: @jerry - perfectly valid email address. zeflex - this would also match your query: `sam@stonybrook.edu.princeton.edu` or `superspamuser@harvard.edu.yourmaliciousdomain.com`

Comment: Well, it's indeed progress, however another test revealed another bug `@mail.sunysuffolk.eduu` will also pass. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news. May be nothing, but worth mentioning.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm working hard on it ... back soon with graal solution :)

Comment: Actually, having those emails in an array like that won't work, because the OP's form will most likely use a form with a single input. When I tested your update without the emails array, it spitted out `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in...` --- Sorry again to be the bearer of bad news. Just to let you know that `voodoo417's` answer is the one that worked even with the added characters to the domains. Thought you'd like to know.